# Какой порядок пикселей в Canvas?

Tags: javascript, canvas, png

Получаю bitmap:

```
var imageObj = new Image();

imageObj.onload = function () {
    var width  = imageObj.width,
        height = imageObj.height;

    var canvas = document.createElement( 'canvas' );
        canvas.width = width;
        canvas.height = height;

    var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

    context.drawImage( imageObj, 0, 0 );

    var bitmap = context.getImageData( 0, 0, width, height ).data;
    // [ r, g, b, a, ... ]
};

imageObj.setAttribute( 'crossOrigin', '' );
imageObj.src = 'https://mdn.mozillademos.org/files/5397/rhino.jpg';
```

Получаю одномерный массив, в котором каждому пикселю соответствует 4 элемента:
*R, G, B и A (альфа-канал)*

Но какой порядок кодирования пикселей?
**Первый пиксель - в каком углу изображения находится?**

***PS*** Да, есть [стандарт PNG](http://png-mng.sourceforge.net/pub/png/), но я в английском не силен там что-то найти...

Comment: левый верхний угол

Comment: PNG здесь ни при чём, браузер его сам декодирует и пихает в Image уже в формате объекта Image

Comment: В `bitmap` у Вас будет одномерный массив, по длине равный произведению ширины и высоты Вашего изображения, увеличенному в 4 раза. А значения цветов будут циклически идти в таком порядке: `a, r, g, b`. Все это можно прочитать в документации MDN

Comment: первый пиксель будет с координатами `х0:у0`, второй `х1:у0`, третий `х2:у0`. Когда `Х` достигнет ширины картинки, `Х` - станет равен `0`, а `У++`, Но пиксели будут в одномерном массиве, как сказано выше

Comment: Значит всё-таки первый пиксель в верхнем левом углу?

Comment: @ЕвгенийГуреев, конечно. От нулевого пикселя в верхнем левом углу до конца строки, потом на новую строку и так далее, пока мы не достигнем последнего пикселя в нижнем правом углу

Comment: Порядок пикселей все таки R,G,B,A , а начало в верхнем левом углу. Благодарю)